# Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false) only supports one subscriber (which is allowed, see reactive-streams specification, rule 1.12)

Tags: scala, sbt

As the title says we are getting such an error and google searching doesn't return anything useful. This rule no longer exists on the specification.

Just wondering if anyone has seen this before please?

Comment: `Sink.asPublisher` isn't standard Scala (and to my knowledge doesn't have anything to do with sbt).  Are you using a library?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned I believe that this is not sbt API. This looks like akka-stream `Sink` (I stumbled upon this question googling exactly about that).

In that case this error basically means that `Publisher` created with fanout set to `false` can only have one subscriber and this error is raised when another subscriber tried to subscribe to the publisher.

I guess that the error message is slightly outdated and it should point to rule `1.11` [here](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm).